# How to enable changing the status of my own Element Type

Tags: craft3, elementtype, modules

So i have created my own Element Type and enabled statuses with the `hasStatuses()` method.

In the ControlPanel its shown that each element has its own status, but it cant be changed. See image below:
[image]

The checkboxes are missing to select the desired entry and then disable or enable it. Im crawling through the source code but i am not able to find a clue on how to enable this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because those buttons are `ActionButtons` and they have actually nothing to do with statuses in general since the status is not a single field value nor is there a value in the DB that's called status. For example: the status of an entry depends on several different attributes like `expiryDate` or the date when it's published so there is no way to set those statuses via button there.

You'll need to register the action buttons for your element type. Just take a look at an entries `defineActions` function.